# Blaze: template inclusion with dynamic content

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I have something quite simple to solve, but couldn't find anything in the doc.

I want to create a reusable component with a title, and when I click on it, it open/close its content. Basically a collapsible accordion.

The only problem is content can vary.

Is something like the following code exists in Blaze ?

```
{{>Accordion title="a title"}}
    <p>a custom paragraph</p>
{{/Accordion}}

{{>Accordion title="another title"}}
    <ul>
        <li>list 1</li>
        <li>list 2</li>
    </ul>
{{/Accordion}}
```

and would render into:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="title">a title</div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>a custom paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <div class="title">another title</div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>list 1</li>
            <li>list 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible ? Or do I have to create a separate Template for the content and call it with `{{> Template.dynamic}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for [custom block helpers](https://guide.meteor.com/blaze.html#block-helpers) ([other source](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#custom-block-helpers)):

```spacebars
<template name="header">  
  <header>
    {{#if ready}}
      {{> Template.contentBlock}}
    {{else}}
      {{> Template.elseBlock}}
    {{/if}}
  </header>
</template>

<template name="examplePage">  
  {{#header ready=Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    Example Page
  {{else}}
    Loading...
  {{/header}}
</template>
```